# Raspberry Pi crash during python program (OR how is it possible to kill Linux???)

Tags: python, linux, memory, raspberry-pi, keypad

I build a keypad activated sensor with a Raspberry Pi and Python. Everything seems to go well but after a few minutes and several keypad entries, the Pi has a total crash and switches off immediately - no error messages pop up.

The script will continously wait for a keypad entry and if the code is correct, switch on a sensor, if it's not you have to try again. If the sensor is activated you have to put in the correct numbers to avoid an alarm being triggered after 30s)

Could anyone point me in the direction of what might be the problem? Here are the things I've tried so far without success

1) Exchange Pi to new Pi 2

2) Different OS, both NOOBS and Raspbian Wheezy

3) Different sensor (accelerometer vs IR sensor)

4) Disconnect monitor, keyboard and use SSH connection via Cygwin

5) Get log file until crash - log file was empty after reboot

```
python bad_script &> full_log.txt
```

6) Different log file command: causes instant crash and is also empty after reboot:

```
python script.py >> /logdir/script.py.log 2>&1
```

The question is: how am I able to crash Linux? If it's a memory problem, isn't there a prevention in linux to stop processed before they appear?

Here is the full script I am running:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import threading
import signal
from matrix_keypad import RPi_GPIO1
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smbus
import time

passcode = [1,2,3,4] # this is the correct code you have to enter
kp = RPi_GPIO1.keypad(columnCount = 3)
alarm_active = threading.Event() # shared variable used to control the sensor monitoring thread
alarm_active.clear() # Clear the alarm initially
monitor_thread = None # Global variable used to store the monitoring thread
#Set up all the pins correctio
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PINIR=7
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)  # infrad-sensor

#Now activate the kaypad and listen for keypad inputs
def digit():
    r = None
    while r == None:
        r = kp.getKey()
    return r

def get_keycode():
    # Function to loop around reading 4 keypresses in a row
    # Compare against chosen code
    # If match, switch the alarm state
    entered = []
    while len(entered) < 4:
        key = digit()
        sleep(0.5)
        print key
        entered.append( key )

    if entered == passcode:
        entered = []
        print "Code correct"
        switch_alarm_state()
    else:
        # Just clear the keypad buffer if the wrong code went in
        # Could say "BAD CODE!" here, or even force immediate alarm perhaps
        print "Wrong Code - Try again"
        GPIO.output(27, True) # let red LED blink as indicator that code was wrong
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(27, False)
        entered = []

def switch_alarm_state():
    # Function to control the state of the alarm
    # If the alarm should be on, run a thread monitoring the sensor
    # If the alarm should be off, make sure the thread is stopped
        global monitor_thread
    if alarm_active.is_set():
        # If the alarm is currently set, stop it
        print "Alarm was abolished"
        GPIO.output(17, False) #switch green LED off
        alarm_active.clear() # Signals to the monitor thread that we wish to shut it down
        monitor_thread.join() # Wait until the monitor thread has stopped
    else:
        # Alarm is not currently set, so start the sensor monitor thread going
        print "Alarm was activated"
        GPIO.output(17, True)
        monitor_thread = threading.Thread( target=sensor_monitor )
        alarm_active.set()
        monitor_thread.start()

def sensor_monitor():
    # Function to be run in a separate thread, monitoring the sensor
    alarm_timer = None # Variable to hold a timer object that will fire the alarm
    while alarm_active.is_set():
        #print xrota
        if GPIO.input(PINIR):
            print "Alarm has been triggered"
            if alarm_timer is None:
                alarm_timer = threading.Timer( 30.0, fire_alarm )
                alarm_timer.start()

        sleep(0.5)

    # The alarm must have been deactivated to get here
    # Stop any outstanding alarms and shutdown
    if alarm_timer is not None:
        alarm_timer.cancel()
    return

def fire_alarm():
    # Here you implement the actions to be carried out by an alarm
    print "Alarm is send to server"
    msg = "Alarm"
    publish.single("alarm/demo",msg, hostname="52.17.194.125") 


def shutdown_handler( signum, frame ):
    # Shut down the child thread nicely
    alarm_active.clear()
    monitor_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__': # This is the Python way to check you are being directly run, and not just imported by another script
    signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler ) # If you stop the script with ctrl+C, make sure it shuts down properly
    signal.signal( signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler )

try:    
    while True:
        get_keycode()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print "Quit program"
```

Comment: Could this be a power draw issue?  How are you powering everything that you have connected to the Pi?

Comment: I have connected the Pi with a USB to my laptop but also used the "official" Rasberry Pi power supply to go straight into the wall (as another test but both fail).   The IR sensor connects to Ground, 3.3V pin and one GPIO bin (although it's the same with another sensor, so don't think it's that one).                                                                                             The keypad doesn't have a separate powersupply, it just connects to 7 GPIO pins. This is the keypad I use: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4-x-3-Membrane-12-Key-Keypad-Arduino-PIC-Raspberry-Pi-/131559589457?